# Filters nested arrays to find unique product collections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopify

I'm building a site with Next.js and Shopify. I need to create a page that will list all the collections that match a certain `productType`.

The only way I've been able to find to get this data from the GraphQL API is to search for all products, filtered by `productType` and try to find all the unique collections from that list.

[Here is an example of what that looks like](https://gist.github.com/lukebennett88/f02aad466a3f92e49ef5fda7002c9397).

How can I get just the unique collections?
I tried this unfortunately it doesn't work:

```js
const collections = [
  ...new Set([
    ...allCollectionsByType.filter(({ node }) => {
      const collection = node.collections.edges;
      return collection[0]?.node;
    }),
  ]),
];
```

Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm really bad at working with nested arrays!

Appreciate any help

Comment: you should reproduce: make (yourself) a small json representing allCollectionsByType, apply your 5 lines, and check the result. If you still can't come to a solution, then update here with your minimal **reproducing** example ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. I realised that the Set couldn't work out that the objects in it were not unique, so I had to stringify them first.

I don't think this is the best implementation (I'm looping through the array several times) but it does work.

Here is my solution to get this to work:

```js
  const collections = allCollectionsByType.map(({ node }) => {
    const collection = node.collections.edges?.[0]?.node;
    return JSON.stringify(collection);
  });

  const unique = Array.from(new Set(collections))
    .filter((node) => typeof node === 'string')
    .map((node: string) => JSON.parse(node));
```